# How to change selenium time.sleep() to WaitForElement in the correct mode in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am web-scraping from a lot of websites, I am using selenium with time.sleep(), but this is a risky way, because sometimes my computer get lagg, and in this way I lose the dataes.

How can I change my code to Wait_For_Element method to avoid losing informations?

Here my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import urllib2
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import contextlib
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

def scrape(urls):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    datatable=[]
    for url in urls:
        browser.get(url)
        html = browser.page_source
        soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
        table = soup.find('table', { "class" : "table table-condensed table-hover data-table m-n-t-15" })
        soup2=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
        name = soup2.h2.string
        soup3=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
        name2 = soup3.h1.string
        soup4=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
        name3 = soup4.h3.string
        soup5=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
        name4 = soup5.find('span' , attrs={'class' : 'clock-time ng-binding'}).text.strip()

        for record in table.find_all('tr', class_="hidden-xs hidden-sm ng-scope"):
            temp_data = []
            temp_data.append(name4)
            temp_data.append(name)
            temp_data.append(name2)    
            temp_data.append(name3)    
            for data in record.find_all("td"):
                temp_data.append(data.text.encode('latin-1'))
            newlist = filter(None, temp_data)
            datatable.append(newlist)

    time.sleep(10) 
    browser.close()
    return datatable
```

Comment: You use `time.sleep()` **after** scraping data. How could it affect on waiting for element? Which exact part of code you need to improve? Also why do you use `BeautifulSoup` (you import `BeautifulSoup` two times) for getting data if you can simply use `Selenium` built-in methods for the same?

Comment: Yes, i did it with an unnecessary complicated way..but it is working..I have to wait to upload this part of table : 'table', { "class" : "table table-condensed table-hover data-table m-n-t-15" }

Comment: You could use a [WebDriverWait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Comment: And if it isn't finding this table, my code is stopping and i get an error message? (because it is bad for me).
Here i have to place this html table code? : "EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "IHAVETOPUTHERETHETABLENAME?"))
Can you write an answer with the correct method, and i can accept it!

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in comments, you can use [`ExplicitWait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to get dynamic element as below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

table = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.table.table-condensed.table-hover.data-table.m-n-t-15")))
```

Comment: In my code where I have to write this and what i have to delete?
I tried more possibility, but not working.

Comment: Instead of `table = soup.find('table', { "class" : "table table-condensed table-hover data-table m-n-t-15" })`. It should return you WebElement

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with this part (table.table.table-condensed.table-hover.data-table.m-n-t-15)? The first webpage is already loaded, but nothing happened, just "waiting". (no error msg)

Comment: Provide `HTML` sample for target table or page URL

Comment: This is the target table : table = soup.find('table', { "class" : "table table-condensed table-hover data-table m-n-t-15" but nothing happend.

Comment: It's not an `HTML`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a small library with reusable methods and use the ExpectedConditions of Selenium.

```
       public void clickWebElementVisible(String element, By by) throws ObjectMissing {

    try {
        Utilities.waitExplicit(1);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(this.driver, 30);
        WebElement x = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
        if (x.isDisplayed()) {
          x.click();
        } else {
            throw new ObjectMissing(" Error in " + getClass() + "." + element + ". Object Missing");
        }
    } catch (WebDriverException x) {
        throw new ObjectMissing(" Error in " + x.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Here element will be helpful for debugging purpose to know which element you were looking for and by is the locator value.

The usage could be as follow

```
clickWebElementVisible("lnkLoginUsername", "Locator");
```

And you can either use  Exception or your custom exception "ObjectMissing"

Comment: public void clickWebElementVisible(EC.presence_of_element_located, By.CSS_SELECTOR "table.table.table-condensed.table-hover.data-table.m-n-t-15")? In my code where I have to write this and what i have to delete?

Comment: This is the example for the method to click on the element on web. You can customize the function for Setting the text, selecting from Select etc. What do you want to achieve...I guess your question was to wait for any element to be displayed on the page. And the wait should be dynamic i.e. as soon as the element is located your script should move ahead. Right?

Comment: Yes, it has to be loaded ('table', { "class" : "table table-condensed table-hover data-table m-n-t-15)  and after i can web-scraping, that's why i used the time.sleep function.

Comment: Then better change the clickWebElement method to `waitForWebElement` and change the if condition to `if (!x.isDisplayed()) {`
          `throw new ObjectMissint("Exception message");` and you are done

Comment: Thus the method will do nothing if the element if found but will throw the exception if the element is missing.